# subdocument query not containing values outside array with regex matching

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection of recipes where each item looks like:

```
{
    name: "Recipe 1",
    ingredients: [{
        name: "dark chocolate",
        qty: "1 g"
    }, {
        name: "milk",
        qty: "2 g"
    }, {
        name: "unsalted butter",
        qty: "3 g"
    }]
}
```

How can I find all recipes that:

- have an ingredient of which the name *either contains* milk *or* chocolate
- but *do not contain any other* ingredients that *do not* either contain milk or chocolate?

The example above would not match that query.

Summary: I need all recipes that contain milk, chocolate or both, but nothing else.

Comment: You could negate looking for choc and milk by using `$not` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/ ) and `$elemMatch` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/ ): `{ ingredients: { $not: { $elemMatch: {name: /chocolate|milk/} } } }` Or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex expression that looks for docs *not* containing `ingredients` of milk or chocolate (using technique from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)) and then negating that with a `$not` does the trick:

```js
db.recipes.find({'ingredients.name': {$not: /^((?!(milk|chocolate)).)*$/}})
```

Tested against:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114f7b748994465c5b5c369"),
  "name": "Recipe 1",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "dark chocolate",
      "qty": "1 g"
    },
    {
      "name": "milk",
      "qty": "2 g"
    },
    {
      "name": "unsalted butter",
      "qty": "3 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114f9f348994465c5b5c36a"),
  "name": "Recipe 2",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "dark chocolate",
      "qty": "1 g"
    },
    {
      "name": "milk",
      "qty": "2 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114fcec48994465c5b5c36b"),
  "name": "Recipe 3",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "milk chocolate",
      "qty": "1 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114fd0e48994465c5b5c36c"),
  "name": "Recipe 4",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "soy",
      "qty": "1 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114fd5248994465c5b5c36d"),
  "name": "Recipe 5",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "chocolate mud",
      "qty": "1 g"
    }
  ]
}
```

It outputs:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114f9f348994465c5b5c36a"),
  "name": "Recipe 2",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "dark chocolate",
      "qty": "1 g"
    },
    {
      "name": "milk",
      "qty": "2 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114fcec48994465c5b5c36b"),
  "name": "Recipe 3",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "milk chocolate",
      "qty": "1 g"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5114fd5248994465c5b5c36d"),
  "name": "Recipe 5",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "chocolate mud",
      "qty": "1 g"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: While your regex indeed seems correct (tested separately), this does not return any results. If I take away the $not operator, it returns everything (while you would assume recipes with either milk or chocolate in the name wouldn't be returned).

Comment: @smhg Hmm...it does work when I try it.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.  See my update.

Comment: which version of mongodb do you use? i'll try it on the same version

Comment: @smhg This is with mongo 2.2.3.

Comment: Aha, the problem on my side is that there are also recipes without ingredients and those are returned too (i was only doing counts). You couldn't know that of course. Thank you for your answer!